# expected identifier instead saw new (a reserved word)

Tags: javascript, jshint

I want to know how can i disable JSHint's checking for this type of declarations, so i can do:

```
obj.new = function(){
    //...
};
```

instead of

```
obj['new'] = function(){
    //...
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `es5` option, since reserved words as property names are only valid as of ES5. Put this directive at the top of the file(s) in question:

```
/*jshint es5: true */
```

However, it's worth bearing in mind that older browsers will throw errors if they encounter such syntax. If your code needs to run in older browsers (notably IE8) then you're better off sticking to the alternative syntax, or using non-reserved words as property identifiers.

**Edit**: I've added a bit more detail about this error to [its page on jslinterrors.com](http://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-identifier-and-instead-saw-a-a-reserved-word/).

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez - You're welcome, glad I could help. Also, be aware that there is a bug in JSLint (and therefore JSHint) when using the `es5` option. It won't affect you in this situation, but it could be one to be aware of. Details are in the link I've added to the question, and in [this pull request](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/744) to JSHint.

Comment: It says "ES5 option is now set per default", but the tip is there still.