# JSLint: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'class' (a reserved word)

Tags: javascript, jslint

JSLint tells me "Expected an identifier and instead saw 'class' (a reserved word)"

```
$("<a/>", {
  class: "fr" // Error appears here
}).attr("data-name", f)
```

**NOTE**: The code runs find without any errors I'm just wondering....

What can I do to get rid of this lint from appearing while still having my function run without errors?

Full code for function...

```
var showFiles = function() {
  listFiles.forEach(function(f) {
    $("[data-action=filetree]").append(
      $("<div/>").append(
        $("<a/>", {
          text: f
        }).attr("data-name", f)
        .attr("data-nme", f)
        .attr("data-location", "file://" + __dirname + "/content/project/" + f),

        $("<a/>", {
          class: "fr"
        }).attr("data-name", f)
        .html("<i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i>")
        .attr("data-delete", "file://" + __dirname + "/content/project/" + f)
      )
    );
  });
};
showFiles();
```

Comment: change `class:` to `"class":`, if you want it to shut up, but it's not an error, it's a warning that it could be an error. lint is to give the dev a heads-up that he _might_ have made a mistake, it's not an up or down quality test. background: `class:` won't work in older IE, or pre-ES5 browsers.

Comment: haha it worked. Can't believe I didn't think of that lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494207/expected-identifier-instead-saw-new-a-reserved-word

Comment: @pol I disagree: this question is about initializing an object with a reserved word as the name of a property, whereas the other question is about _accessing_ one. Those are two distinct scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also disable JSLint at the file scope or at the single-line scope by using a directive in the comments. This [section from the JSLint documentation](https://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-identifier-and-instead-saw-a-a-reserved-word) seems to point to the rule that is applying. You should be able to disable it by writing something like.

```
/*jshint es5: false */
```

Hopefully this helps, and it may be more preferable than quoting your object property names.